# magento backend page is off alignment. How do I fix that?

Tags: magento

I don't know what happened to my backend when I was working in magneto. All of sudden, now the pages are not showing up in alignment and it is hard to fix when some of the sidebar covered up the page. How do I fix this? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kOGz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on view on the top bar and then click "actual size". Solved. Thank you.